# How do I make correct DPI for PNGs in Android apps?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am very new to Android apps and though this isn't a lot to do with programming, I could use a little guidance. I understand there are a gazillion screensizes for Android and you could make thousands of bitmaps for just one app.

To understand better, I researched a lot of pages, but these stood out the most:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/30/designing-for-android/

I am not a developer and don't have a hand in that part (which I feel could really be beneficial to me right now). My only task is to extract `PNGs` from `PSDs` so they fit the different general screen sizes: small, normal, large, and xl whith each size supporting the different `DPI`.

My question is...what's the best and most efficient way to do this besides coding? I've been looking at Table 3 on the Android screen support page and I'm just a bit confused. There are blank spots in the table, for example, on the Large screen row. When you make a large screen with `hdpi` do you keep the screen size the same as the `mdpi (480x800)` and just increase your `dpi`? The same question applies to the other blank spots on the table.

Also, can you consider `PPI` to be the same as `DPI`? So if I set a `PSD` to the same resolution as a small screen with `ldpi` and change the `PNGs` to `120ppi`, is that correct? I've been reading a lot on it and there seems to be no definite answer or way to do this.

As you can see I am all over the place.......

Comment: decrease your dpi to reduce the image size. android handle dpi itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with different

```
<ImageView
    android:scaleType="..."
```

options to fit different screen sizes best. Also you can try to use 9-patch images.

For creating small pictures like any kind of icons you can use Android Asset Studio (just add Android Icon Set as resource in Eclipse) - it will generate icons for different screen densities for you.